# How to update nz(nRes\[1\] code to version 5

Tags: pine-script

It is working wersion 3 or later, I cunldn't cope with updating to version 5.
Thank You in advance

```
study(title="Volatility", shorttitle="Volatility")
Length = input(10, minval=1)
xATR = atr(Length)
nRes = ((Length - 1) \* nz(nRes\[1\], 0) + xATR) / Length
plot(nRes, color=blue, title="lineA")
```

not working

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Volatility", shorttitle="Volatility")
Length = input.int(10, minval=1)
xATR = ta.atr(Length)
//float nRes = na
//var float nRes = na
nRes = ((Length - 1) \* nz(nRes\[1\] , 0) + xATR) / Length
plot(nRes, color=color.new(color.blue,10), title="lineB")
```

your text`

I tried this , but error shows

```
var float nRes = na
if nRes\[1\] == na()
nRes = ((Length - 1) \* 0 + xATR) / Length
else
nRes = ((Length - 1) \* nz(nRes\[1\] , 0) + xATR) / Length
```

Comment: \\* nz(nRes\\[1\\] - what does it mean, these symbols \ doesn't work on any pine's version.
Check your original code that works on version=3, most likely these symbols aren't in the code

Comment: The first code from upper is working , it is written in version 3. This is original code.  The code below sentence " not working" is changed to version 5 and doesn't work. I don't know how to change code.

Comment: if you copy and paste your code from first code block it doesn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Volatility", overlay = false)
Length = input.int(10, minval=1)
xATR = ta.atr(Length)
var float nRes = 0.0`
nRes := ((Length - 1) * nz(nRes[1], 0) + xATR) / Length
plot(nRes, color=color.blue, title="Volatility")
```

Comment: Just the code in the answer is not the best way to explain the problem.
Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.
The problematic code does not have problems with conversion; it contains incorrect symbols with which the author is trying to convert it. It would be worth explaining this to him so that in the future he will read error messages more carefully and check the syntax